# Unable to convert Spark RDD to Schema RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute the example provided in Spark programming guide.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html

But I am facing the compilation error.
(I am a Scala newbie)

Below is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext,SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql

object Temp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SPARK SQL example")
        val sc= new SparkContext(sparkConf)
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
        case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
        val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
        people.registerTempTable("people")
        val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
        teenagers.map(t => "Name: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)
    }
}
```

I am facing the compilation error `No TypeTag available for Person` at the line `people.registerTempTable("people")`.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Answered here http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/SparkSQL-registerAsTable-No-TypeTag-available-Error-td7623.html You need to move the case class definition outside of main so it's not an inner class.

Answer (score 4):

It is failing because the Person class is defined inside of the function and as such the Scala compiler will not create a TypeTag for the class.  As Paul suggested you can move it out of the function to the top level.

I'll add that there is a JIRA to relax this restriction: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4842